# Clang static analysis separately from build?

Tags: clang, static-analysis, scan-build

Is it possible to perform the clang static analysis after the build? 
Something like `scan-build <file>`

I tried using scan-build  but it always returns `No bugs found` and running `scan-build cmake ..` and `scan-build make` seems the only way to actually get the bugs